# linking the query in the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[From the query i am able to return the output as expected ..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38634/20)

Is it possible to write the same query in the below marked quotes using select statement:

```
SELECT ACC.ACCOUNT_NUM AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   ACC.ACCOUNT_NAME AS ACCOUNT_NAME,
   ADR.ADDRESS_1 AS BUILDING_TYPE,
   ACC.CUSTOMER_REF AS CUSTOMER_ID,
   CAT.BC AS BILL_CYCLE,
   CES.EVENT_SOURCE AS TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
   AAT.PACKAGE_NAME AS PROMO_PACKAGE,
   PRD.PRODUCT_NAME AS SERVICES,
   (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT (EVENT_SOURCE))
      FROM CUSTEVENTSOURCE CES1
     WHERE CES1.CUSTOMER_REF = ACC.CUSTOMER_REF AND END_DTM IS NULL)
      AS TOTAL_NUMBER,
   ("SELECT LISTAGG (EVENT_SOURCE, ', ')
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EVENT_SOURCE)
      FROM CUSTEVENTSOURCE
     WHERE CUSTOMER_REF = ACC.CUSTOMER_REF AND END_DTM IS NULL")
      AS ALL_IPHONE_NUMBERS,
   CUS.COMPANY_NAME AS COMPANY_NAME,
      ADR.ADDRESS_1
   || ' '
   || ADR.ADDRESS_2
   || ' '
   || ADR.ADDRESS_3
   || ' '
   || ADR.ADDRESS_4
   || ' '
   || ADR.ADDRESS_5
      AS BILLING_ADDRESS,
   (SELECT ADR.ADDRESS_1
      FROM ADDRESS ADR
     WHERE ADR.CUSTOMER_REF = ACC.CUSTOMER_REF
           AND ADDRESS_SEQ IN
                  (SELECT ADDRESS_SEQ
                     FROM CUSTPRODUCTADDRESS CPA
                    WHERE CPA.CUSTOMER_REF = ADR.CUSTOMER_REF
                          AND PRODUCT_SEQ IN
                                 (SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ
                                    FROM CUSTPRODUCTSTATUS CPS
                                   WHERE CPS.CUSTOMER_REF =
                                            CPA.CUSTOMER_REF
                                         AND EFFECTIVE_DTM =
                                                (SELECT MAX (
                                                           EFFECTIVE_DTM)
                                                   FROM CUSTPRODUCTSTATUS CPS1
                                                  WHERE CPS1.CUSTOMER_REF =
                                                           CPS.
                                                            CUSTOMER_REF))))
      AS INSTALLATION_ADDRESS,
   (SELECT ACS.EFFECTIVE_DTM
      FROM ACCOUNTSTATUS ACS
     WHERE ACS.ACCOUNT_NUM = ACC.ACCOUNT_NUM
           AND ACS.EFFECTIVE_DTM =
                  (SELECT MAX (EFFECTIVE_DTM)
                     FROM ACCOUNTSTATUS ACS1
                    WHERE ACS1.ACCOUNT_NUM = ACS.ACCOUNT_NUM
                          AND ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'OK'))
      AS ACTIVATION_DATE,
   (SELECT ACS.ACCOUNT_STATUS
      FROM ACCOUNTSTATUS ACS
     WHERE ACS.ACCOUNT_NUM = ACC.ACCOUNT_NUM
           AND ACS.EFFECTIVE_DTM =
                  (SELECT MAX (EFFECTIVE_DTM)
                     FROM ACCOUNTSTATUS ACS1
                    WHERE ACS1.ACCOUNT_NUM = ACS.ACCOUNT_NUM))
      AS ACCOUNT_STATUS,
   (SELECT ACS.STATUS_REASON_TXT
      FROM ACCOUNTSTATUS ACS
```

can u please help me out..I am new to sql..please

Thanks in advance..

The above needs to be changed within the "" double quotes
The output looks like:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER     ACCOUNT_NAME  BUILDING_TYPE  CUSTOMER_ID  TELEPHONE_NUMBER  PROMO_PACKAGE TOTAL_NUMBER   ALL_IPHONE_NUMBERS,

MTX000110       John             xxxx            10002         123456     yyy    3   001-003,004,007
```

If the account has 3 totoal_number then in the All_iphone_numbers column if the values have sequenced numbers then it should '-' with separator otherwise it has to display the number

If I use the " " doubl quoted array..I am getting the output as comma separated values whic is incorrec result..the result should looks like "if the values have sequenced numbers then it should '-' with separator otherwise it has to display the number".

Comment: I would be willing to help, but the query is so complex and the question doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks for the sqlfiddle, now can you tell me what you'd like to do differently? Perhaps, show me some example output or explain what's different (or the same) about the sqlfiddle?

Comment: @JoeLove: I have edited the qurey, Please look into that..and pls help me in solving the problem..

Comment: What DB type are you using. I'm most familiar with oracle and postgress and it looks like you're using something else.

Comment: I am using 11 version of oracle

Comment: What happens when you take the double quotes out of the query? Are you getting an error or just incorrect results?

Comment: Please sir...Please help me out...i am unable to proceed further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (Note: I dont have 11G R2, so I used wm_concat to test it, which is not supported, but if you have 11G R2, then use LISTAGG)

```
WITH TABIBITOSAN
    AS (SELECT
             ACCOUNT_REF,
             "number",
             TO_NUMBER ( "number" )
             - ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER ( "number" ))
                 AS GRP
        FROM
             TBL),
    DATASET1
    AS (SELECT
             ACCOUNT_REF,
             CASE
                 WHEN MIN ( "number" ) = MAX ( "number" )
                 THEN
                     MIN ( "number" )
                 ELSE
                        MIN ( "number" )
                     || '-'
                     || MAX ( "number" )
             END
                 AS RANGES
        FROM
             TABIBITOSAN
        GROUP BY
             ACCOUNT_REF,
             GRP
        ORDER BY
             ACCOUNT_REF,
             MIN ( "number" ))
SELECT
      ACCOUNT_REF,
      WM_CONCAT ( RANGES ) AS NEW_RANGES
FROM
      DATASET1
GROUP BY
      ACCOUNT_REF;
```

**Results:**

```
101 002-004,006-008,011
```

**Using LISTAGG**

```
SELECT
      ACCOUNT_REF,
      LISTAGG ( RANGES,
              ',' )
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RANGES)
          AS NEW_RANGES
FROM
      DATASET1
WHERE
      ACCOUNT_REF = ACC.ACCOUNT_REF
GROUP BY
      ACCOUNT_REF
```

Comment: can i use the format (which u have given) inside the "select" statement..??Because here i should not use any functions...for implementing this..framework will not support the usageof functions..

Comment: Really confused. Place the exact scenario, rewrite your question, add the inputs and exact outputs you need to see and more importantly share the relevant snippets you used so far

Comment: I want to use the same thing which u have given in my query in place of double "" quotes of select query.

Comment: select ACC.ACCOUNT_NUM AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,.....with TABIBITOSAN
    AS (SELECT
             ACCOUNT_REF,
             "number",
             TO_NUMBER ( "number" )
             - ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER ( "number" ))) Is it possible??

Comment: It should be `WITH X AS (SELECT SOMETHING), Y AS (SELECT * FROM X) SELECT FROM X,Y;` So you can use the snippet at the last select and not in the CTE.